# Yii - inserting null values in db, 'safe' attribute set

Tags: php, mysql, json, yii

I'm using Yii as a php backend for a mobile app using REST API. I can see that the xhr data object on the client contains the correct json-encoded values. I have the 'safe' attribute set in my model class like this:

```
array('user_id, last_visit, first_visit, blah, 'safe', 'on'=>'search')
```

And the insert occurs as intended. The only problem is that `null` values are getting inserted for all fields except the auto-increment primay key. I followed this helpful blog almost verbatim, [Create a REST API](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api), and it works quite simply and well. I just don't know how to debug the null value inserts.

I fire this method on the client side

`upload.open("POST", "http://localhost:8888/dashboard/index.php/api/tracker");`

then send it

`upload.send(JSON.stringify(_xhrData));`

which then calls this method on the server:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        switch ($_GET['model']) {
            // Get an instance of the respective model
            case 'tracker':
                $model = new Tracker;
                break;
            default:
                $this->_sendResponse(501,
                    sprintf('Mode <b>create</b> is not implemented for model <b>%s</b>',
                        $_GET['model']));
                Yii::app()->end();
        }
        // Try to assign POST values to attributes
        foreach ($_POST as $var => $value) {
            // Does the model have this attribute? If not raise an error
            if ($model->hasAttribute($var))
                $model->$var = $value;
            else
                $this->_sendResponse(500,
                    sprintf('Parameter <b>%s</b> is not allowed for model <b>%s</b>', $var,
                        $_GET['model']));
        }
        // Try to save the model
        if ($model->save())
            $this->_sendResponse(200, CJSON::encode($model));
        else {
            // Errors occurred
            $msg = "<h1>Error</h1>";
            $msg .= sprintf("Couldn't create model <b>%s</b>", $_GET['model']);
            $msg .= "<ul>";
            foreach ($model->errors as $attribute => $attr_errors) {
                $msg .= "<li>Attribute: $attribute</li>";
                $msg .= "<ul>";
                foreach ($attr_errors as $attr_error)
                    $msg .= "<li>$attr_error</li>";
                $msg .= "</ul>";
            }
            $msg .= "</ul>";
            $this->_sendResponse(500, $msg);
        }
    }
```

I get no errors, just the following status message on the client

`[INFO] {"user_id":"19","last_visit":null,"first_visit":null,"locale":null,"this_visit":null,"latitude":null,"longitude":null,"device_maker":null,"device_model":null,"os_platform":null,"os_version":null,"opted_out":null,"opted_in":null,"modified":null,"model_type":null}`

I would greatly appreciate any help on debugging this. Thanks.

Comment: remove `"on"=>"search"`

Comment: @AlirezaFallah I removed it, but it had no effect. Same result as before.

Comment: Could you please tell me where and how do you pass your data through REST?

Comment: I have a REST function in my mobile app that retrieves the record(s) in local storage, json-formats them, then sends the data object via the URL as a POST. That part works because I tested it with a generic REST API. So, that's not the problem. The problem is the $_POST values aren't getting properly assigned to the db object.

Comment: Could you please try if ($model->hasAttribute($var)) $this->_sendResponse(200,$var) or $value ?

Comment: I did this `if ($model->hasAttribute($var))
                    $this->_sendResponse(200, $var);`. Got the same results as before. Also, try putting back ticks around your code. Makes it easier to see what you want me to try.

Comment: Did you try checking if there are indeed values in your `$_POST`?

Answer (score 0):

Most probable reason is that your data is not posted properly. Try to print $_POST and see what it returns.

```
print_r($_POST);
```